# ng-repeat inside ng-repeat not working in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using two ng repeats but the second one it doesnt display. Let me show you my view :

```
<div  class="post" ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'username':false" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
  <p>{{user.username}}</p> 
  <small><a ng-click='gotomessages(user.username)' class="btn btn-default">go</a></small>     
  <small class="pull-right"> Message</small>
  <div ng-repeat="message in messages[$index]">
    <p>{{message.name}}</p>   
  </div>
</div>
```

the $index is the one of the first ng-repeat. Is it possible to use it like i did ? In anyway the second ng repeat doesnt work can you help

Comment: Each ng-repeat creates a new scope

Comment: so is it possible to do what i intend to do ? Meaning is it possible to have a variable tha incrments the second ng-repeats array ?

Comment: Have you tried $parent.$index

Comment: there *are* ways to accomplish this task, but it is infinitely easier (and clearer) to accomplish this kind of logic using the ControllerAs syntax rather than `$scope`.  if you are able to post a [mcve] for review, it would be easier for that or other alternatives to be presented.

Comment: there is an often ignored rule in Angular "Always use a dot in bindings.".  When you ignore this rule, you end up having to resort to things like `$parent` to help angular to understand what scope you are looking for your properties in.  This definitely works, but isn't the best (or cleanest) solution, especially when exposing this code to others who may not know the structure of your backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `$parent.messages[$index]` instead of `messages[$index]` in the second `ng-repeat`

Comment: @julianaMorales great. Please upvote and accept my answer.